# How to prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum {a_n}^2 x^n$ is $\mathcal{R}^2$ without appealing to Cauchy–Hadamard?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let ($a_n$) be a sequence of real numbers and let 0 < $\mathcal{R}$ < ∞
be the convergence radius of the power series $\sum {a_n} x^n$;

Prove or disprove :
The radius of converges of the series $\sum {a_n}^2 x^n$ is $\mathcal{R}^2$.

It looks like proof, the naive solution is to use Cauchy–Hadamard theorem, but we don't know that the limit of $a_n$ exists in the extended sense. We've already proved that if $x_1$  ∈   $\mathbb{R}$ and if  $\mathcal{R}$ ≠ ∞ and |$x_1$| > $\mathcal{R}$, then lim [$a_n x_1^n$]≠ 0. I would like to know how to approach that.

New note: we cannot use Cauchy–Hadamard theorem due to my Teaching Assitant, Do you have another way, by using the proof I've provided?

Comment: Do you know a formula for computing $\mathcal R$?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764842/proving-that-the-radius-of-convergence-of-a-power-series-is-r-1-lim-sup-sqr?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [radii of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n }^2z^n$??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135453/radii-of-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-a-n-z2n-and-sum-n-1-infty-a)

Comment: @AnneBauval our Teaching Assistant told us to not use 
Cauchy–Hadamard theorem because we've only defined it when the lim of $a_n$ exists in the extended sense and we don't define it with sup. He told us that using this theorem is not acceptable in that case and to use the hint I wrote instead.

Comment: Ok, I understand and retract my vote to close as a duplicate.